# Как сделать проверку пользовательского вводе через SQLite?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlite, telebot

Всех приветствую!
Подскажите, как сделать проверку пользовательского ввода через базу данных SQLite.
Необходимо, чтобы пользователь ввел число, которое есть в базе данных в определенной строке и выполнились определенные действия.
Покажу на примере кода:

```
def onetwofre(message):
    try:
        line_number = message.text
        check = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Table_table WHERE line_number=?', (line_number, )).fetchone()
        if (message.text.isdigit()) and : # Вот тут застрял, какое условие необходимо поставить?
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Именно этот номер и нужен, вы отправили число, которое есть в таблице')
        if (message.text.isdigit()) and (check is None):
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы отправили число, которого нет в таблице')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы отправили что угодно, но не число.')
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка')
```

**Если пользователь вводит номер, который есть в таблице, то fetchone возвращает всю строку.
Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы возвращалось True или если возвращается какое-то значение, то выполнялось бы первое условие?**

Если пользователь вводит число, которого нет в таблице, то fetchone возвращает None, что соответствует условию и цикл срабатывает.

Если пользователь вводит текст или что-то другое, срабатывает третье условие.

Comment: очевидно, что нужно проверять что возвращает fetchone, если числа нет в таблице, то вернется пустой кортеж - False, если кортеж не пустой - True

Comment: @Сlark Devlin , т.е.  if (message.text.isdigit()) and check is True?
Пока не получается, если не сложно добавьте пример в ответ, я заодно смогу его отметить.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых если нужно проверить значение конкретной переменной, то не следует извлекать из БД всю строку, а лучше извлечь конкретное проверяемое значение, например вместо:

```
check = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Table_table WHERE line_number=?', (line_number, )).fetchone()
```

лучше выполнить:

```
check = cursor.execute('SELECT column_name FROM Table_table WHERE line_number=?', (line_number, )).fetchone()
```

Если пользовательский ввод доступен по message.text, и типы данных введенных пользователем совпадают с типом полученным из БД, то можно попробовать вот так:

```
if (message.text.isdigit()) and message.text == check[0]:
```

Comment: Т.е. в условный 'column_name' правильно было бы ввести line_number?
И если пользовательский ввод совпадает с выведенным из таблицы числом, то выполняется это конкретное условие?
Пробую, но пока не получается, уходит в ошибку.

Comment: Когда ввожу число, которого нет в таблице и предполагается выполнение второго условия с None.
Ругается на проверку первого if с message.text == check[0]. Ошибка: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Вероятно результат запроса в БД возвращает None и необходимо реализовать проверку результата запроса к БД на возвращаемый тип данных.